# Angular 4 node_modules

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning Angular 4 and plan to build an App this weekend.

`node_modules` is ginormous. 217 MB for a JavaScript Framework and over 700 subdirectories under node_modules!

Now, I did take a look at the HTML generated and it does not appear to reference `node_modules`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Question: can I not deploy node_modules?  Will Angular 4 still function correctly?**

Comment: When you're ready to run your production build you use `ng build --prod` and then copy the contents of your `dist` folder.

Comment: @Z.Bagley Nice ... I just tried this and it worked out great, bundled JS files less than 1 MB.

Comment: Compact, encoded, and multi-browser effective. Few frameworks can compete with Angular ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Angular2 uses Webpack](https://angular.io/guide/webpack) when it's built. Additionally, [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) bundles all of the used files from node_modules folder into the `vendor.bundle.js`. I believe the rest of the Javascript generated is put into the `main.bundle.js`.

The `node_modules` folder is really only intended to be a development environment and it's not wise to push that folder to production.

Answer (score 0):

running command ng build --prod will convert all your components into a single js file and it generates a dist folder with index.html and all other configurations required to run in production environment. Just place that folder in your web host.

Answer (score 0):

All the node modules you have and all other dependencies that you may install in the future if you suffix `--save` they'll get added to the `package.json` file and the dependencies hierarchy of that module also gets locked in `package-lock.json`.You don't have to store all the enormous node-modules on your repository hence saves space you can upload the dist file or just install the node-modules on the server by command `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

**VERSION CONTROL**

You should include node_modules in your .gitignore file, so it gets ignored from being uploaded in your version control.

**DEPLOYMENT**

As long as you have all the dependencies included in the package.json, you can add `npm install` as a part of the build script in package.json. It will install all necessary packages and package them in your builds automatically.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "npm install && ng build --prod --build-optimizer"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Node_Modules are never be included directly in your deployment ready code. Webpack is a build tool used by default by Angular which bundles your source files and only the required node_module functions into main.bundle.js and vendor.bundle.js respectively. Refer the following link if you want to know what each file consists of in the dist folder created [1](https://upgradetoangular.com/angular-news/the-angular-cli-is-a-great-way-to-build-your-angular-app-but-what-it-does-can-be-a-mystery-what-are-those-files-it-generates/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21733059)

Comment: @Mureinik This is not a link-only answer, it includes far more than just the link.